# Why is my list of length 1 when i append my empty list?

Tags: python, list, append, dimensions

I am trying to append an empty list with outputs of a function with a range of input values. I then want to plot the inputs against the outputs. However, the dimension of the resulting list is said to be 1, but when I print the list itself, it seems to show many entries. I therefore can not plot the input vs output due to differences in dimension. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S - I'm very much in the early stages of learning Python again so I'm sure this is a rudimentary problem.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pylab
from sympy import *

Um,x,x0,alpha=symbols('Um x x0 alpha', real=True)
U = Um*((1-exp(-alpha*(x-x0)))**2-1)

F=-U.diff(x)

x = np.arange(0,30,0.1)
y=[]
y.append(-2*Um*alpha*(1 - exp(-alpha*(x - x0)))*exp(-alpha*(x - x0)))

alpha = 2.287 
x0=1.2
Um=7.37
exp=math.exp


print(len(y))
print(y)
pylab.plot(x,y)
pylab.show()
```

Comment: what is the output of `print(y)` you are getting ?

Comment: Could you please show the "many entries" you see in `y`? In your code you only add one value to this list.

Answer (score 0):

Since the element that you want to append to `y` is a list, it is appended as single element, which contains several items. That's why the length of `y` is 1.

In order to add the elements of list into another list, you can use `extend`, which is basically a list concatenation.

Change `append` to `extend`:

```
y.extend(-2*Um*alpha*(1 - exp(-alpha*(x - x0)))*exp(-alpha*(x - x0)))
```

Comment: Without explanation this is not overly useful.